# JavaScript Checking Array Out of Bounds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a matrix as arena and a small matrix as player. With keys user can move around. `move(pos)` takes argument and inside checks

```
if(pos=="down")
    if (!collide(pos)) player.pos.y++;
```

And collide works like

```
if(pos=="down")
    for (i = 0; i < player.matrix.length; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < player.matrix[i].length; j++)
        {
            if ((player.matrix[i][j] && arena[player.pos.y + i + 1][player.pos.x + j]) != 0) result = true;
        }
    }
```

This woks perfect till you come edge to the arena. When you come to edge, because *there is no lenght+1* index, if detection gives you `Cannot read property of "" undefined`. I tried first checking if typeof index out of bound == undefined however even this gave me the same error. Then I tried **try catch** but the next function inside the **catch** stuck between first one and itself. Any ideas to find an easy solution for checking out of bonds?

Comment: Your first condition of the if statement could check whether the item with the index in question even exists.  for example: `if(item[index] && ... )`.  What will happen is any non-existent item will immediately be false on this first condition.

Comment: @snapjs How can I get undefined rather than Cannot read property 'number' of undefined? I need to force it return something rather than throwing error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is just to protect `arena[player.pos.y + i + 1][player.pos.x + j]` call by length comparisons:

```
for (i = 0; i < player.matrix.length; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < player.matrix[i].length; j++)
  { // here we have an additional protection of arena dimensions
    if(player.pos.y + i + 1 < arena.length && player.pos.x + j < arena[player.pos.y + i + 1].length)
    {
      if ((player.matrix[i][j] && arena[player.pos.y + i + 1][player.pos.x + j]) != 0)
        result = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Also you may implement an additional method on `arena` object:

```
arena.isValid = function(a, b) {
  // check for dimensions
  if(a >= arena.length || b >= arena[a].length) {
    return false;
  }
  // check if the value is undefined/null/0/false/""
  if(!arena[a][b]) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```

And so

```
for (i = 0; i < player.matrix.length; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < player.matrix[i].length; j++)
    if(player.matrix[i][j] && arena.isValid(player.pos.y + i + 1, player.pos.x + j))
      result = true;
```

Comment: @hello_guys I updated the answer to provide more functionality on the `arena` protection.